# Get few information of virtual machines using PowerCLI

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi, powershell-cmdlet, powercli

I am using PowerCLI on RHEL to fetch information from VMs.
I have searched many websites, but I am not getting how to find this details like:

Established connections of VM,

Load Average,

Top Processes,

Process Counts..

It would be a grateful, if anybody knows how to get these details using PowerCLI...

note: I think there are cmdlets which work for windows powerCLi, but doesn't for RHEL.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke-VMScript is going to be the cmdlet you'll want to use to obtain that sort of information, however it is not yet functional in the PowerCLI Core fling.

Note: The PowerCLI Core fling isn't a supported VMware release and it also has a dependency on using the PowerShell Alpha release... where as PowerShell is on Beta and even RC builds.

The goal is certainly to make it functional on PowerShell 6.0, but it's not there yet.